# Option menu icon is not showing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I'm trying to make an options menu with icons. I'm following [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus) but it's not working. And when I went through previously asked similar questions, they all are pointing towards setting showAsAction always or ifRoom. But I want to make it work while it's set as disabled.

```
app:showAsAction="never"
```

This is what I've in my menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/aq"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_comment_24"
        android:title="Ask Query"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ri"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_report_problem_24"
        android:title="Report Issue"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/feed"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_feedback_24"
        android:title="Feedback"/>
</menu>
```

But what I want to do is working with sub menu in the same activity:

```
 <item
        android:title="More">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_comment_24"
                android:title="Check"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_more_vert_24"
        android:title="more"
        app:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/aq"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_comment_24"
                android:title="Ask Query"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/ri"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_report_problem_24"
                android:title="Report Issue"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/feed"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_feedback_24"
                android:title="Feedback"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Doing it this way helped me achieve what I want. [This](https://www.codingdemos.com/android-options-menu-icon/) article helped me with it.